# what to change to use it in other worksheet of same xls

Tags: excel, vba

```
Option Explicit
Dim numRows1 As Integer

Sub GetData()
    Dim ParameterSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ticker As String
    Dim exchange As String
    Dim interval As Integer
    Dim numPastTradingDays As Integer
    Dim qurl As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set ParameterSheet = Sheets("Parameters")
    Set DataSheet = Sheets("Data")

    Dim Fields1() As String
    Fields1 = Split(ParameterSheet.Range("ticker").Value, ",")

    DataSheet.Cells.Clear
    DataSheet.Range("e24") = "Spread"
    DataSheet.Range("f24") = "Average"
    ticker = Fields1(0)
    exchange = ParameterSheet.Range("exchange").Value
    interval = ParameterSheet.Range("interval").Value
    numPastTradingDays = ParameterSheet.Range("numTradingDays").Value

    qurl = "http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?" & _
           "q=" & ticker & _
           "&x=NSE" & _
           "&i=" & interval & _
           "&p=" & numPastTradingDays & "d" & _
           "&f=c"
           '"&f=d,o,h,l,c"


QueryQuote:
    With DataSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, Destination:=DataSheet.Range("a18"))
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = True
    End With

    DataSheet.Range("a18").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=DataSheet.Range("a18"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                                      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
                                                      Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=False

    DataSheet.Columns("A:G").ColumnWidth = 12

    '===Convert Google timestamp to Excel timestamp (only for Windows)
    Dim timeStamp As Double
    Dim timeStampRaw As String
    Dim timeZoneOffsetRaw As String
    Dim timeZoneOffset As Variant

    Dim i As Integer
    numRows1 = DataSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count - 1
    numRows1 = numRows1 + 17
    timeZoneOffsetRaw = DataSheet.Range("a24")
    timeZoneOffset = (Mid(timeZoneOffsetRaw, InStr(timeZoneOffsetRaw, "=") + 1, 10))

    For i = 25 To numRows1

        If Not IsNumeric(DataSheet.Range("a" & i)) Then

            timeStampRaw = DataSheet.Range("a" & i)
            timeStamp = (Mid(timeStampRaw, 2, Len(timeStampRaw) - 1))
            timeStamp = (timeStamp + timeZoneOffset * 60)
            DataSheet.Range("b" & i) = timeStamp / 86400 + 25569

        Else

            DataSheet.Range("b" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-6]*" & interval & "+" & timeStamp & ")/86400+25569"

        End If

    Next

    DataSheet.Range("b8:b" & numRows1).NumberFormat = "d mmm yyyy h:mm;@"
    DataSheet.Range("B:B").Columns.AutoFit
    'DataSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    Call GetData2

End Sub

Sub GetData2()
    Dim ParameterSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ticker2 As String
    Dim exchange As String
    Dim interval As Integer
    Dim numPastTradingDays As Integer
    Dim qurl As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set ParameterSheet = Sheets("Parameters")
    Set DataSheet = Sheets("Data")

    '--DataSheet.Cells.Clear
    Dim Fields() As String
    Fields = Split(ParameterSheet.Range("ticker").Value, ",")
    'Print Fields(0) 'Name
    'Print Fields(1) 'Dept

    'ticker2 = ParameterSheet.Range("ticker").Value
    ticker2 = Fields(1)
    exchange = ParameterSheet.Range("exchange").Value
    interval = ParameterSheet.Range("interval").Value
    numPastTradingDays = ParameterSheet.Range("numTradingDays").Value

    qurl = "http://www.google.com/finance/getprices?" & _
           "q=" & ticker2 & _
           "&x=NSE" & _
           "&i=" & interval & _
           "&p=" & numPastTradingDays & "d" & _
            "&f=c"
           '"&f=d,o,h,l,c"

QueryQuote:
    With DataSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;" & qurl, Destination:=DataSheet.Range("i18"))
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = True
    End With

    DataSheet.Range("i18").CurrentRegion.TextToColumns Destination:=DataSheet.Range("i18"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
                                                      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
                                                      Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, other:=False

    DataSheet.Columns("I:O").ColumnWidth = 12

    '===Convert Google timestamp to Excel timestamp (only for Windows)
    Dim timeStamp As Double
    Dim timeStampRaw As String
    Dim timeZoneOffsetRaw As String
    Dim timeZoneOffset As Variant
    Dim numRows As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim x As Integer
    numRows = DataSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count - 1

    timeZoneOffsetRaw = DataSheet.Range("i24")
    timeZoneOffset = (Mid(timeZoneOffsetRaw, InStr(timeZoneOffsetRaw, "=") + 1, 10))

    For i = 25 To numRows

        If Not IsNumeric(DataSheet.Range("i" & i)) Then

            timeStampRaw = DataSheet.Range("i" & i)
            timeStamp = (Mid(timeStampRaw, 2, Len(timeStampRaw) - 1))
            timeStamp = (timeStamp + timeZoneOffset * 60)
            DataSheet.Range("j" & i) = timeStamp / 86400 + 25569

        Else

            DataSheet.Range("j" & i).FormulaR1C1 = "=(RC[-6]*" & interval & "+" & timeStamp & ")/86400+25569"

        End If

    Next

    DataSheet.Range("j8:j" & numRows).NumberFormat = "d mmm yyyy h:mm;@"
    DataSheet.Range("J:J").Columns.AutoFit

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic


    '----Logic for spread and average
    'For i = 1 To (numRows + 7)

    'For i = 1 to

    For i = 25 To (numRows1 + 1)
        If i = 1 Then
          i = i + 24
        Else
        End If
        If Trim(DataSheet.Range("a" & i)) = "" Or Trim(DataSheet.Range("i" & i)) = "" Then

        Else
         DataSheet.Range("e" & i) = "=" & (DataSheet.Range("a" & i) & "/" & DataSheet.Range("i" & i))
        End If

    Next

   ' If numRows1 = 24 Then
   '     DataSheet.Range("e25") = "=" & (DataSheet.Range("a25") & "/" & DataSheet.Range("i25"))
   ' ElseIf numRows1 = 25 Then
   '     DataSheet.Range("e26") = "=" & (DataSheet.Range("a26") & "/" & DataSheet.Range("i26"))
   ' ElseIf numRows1 = 26 Then
   '     DataSheet.Range("e27") = "=" & (DataSheet.Range("a27") & "/" & DataSheet.Range("i27"))
   ' End If


    i = 0


    If Trim(DataSheet.Range("e" & (numRows1 + 1))) = "" Then
       numRows1 = numRows1 - 1
    End If
    For i = 1 To (numRows1 + 1)
        If i = 1 Then
          i = i + 24
        Else

        End If
       ' If numRows1 = 24 Then
       '     DataSheet.Range("f25") = "=" & "Average(" & (DataSheet.Range("e25") & "/" & DataSheet.Range("e25")) & ")"
       ' ElseIf numRows1 = 25 Then
       '     DataSheet.Range("f25") = "=" & "Average(" & (DataSheet.Range("e25") & "/" & DataSheet.Range("e26")) & ")"
        '    DataSheet.Range("f26") = "=" & "Average(" & (DataSheet.Range("e26") & "/" & DataSheet.Range("e26")) & ")"
       ' Else

        'DataSheet.Range("f" & i) = "=" & "Average(" & (DataSheet.Range("e" & i) & ":" & DataSheet.Range("e" & (numRows1 + 1))) & ")"
        If i = 25 Then
          DataSheet.Range("f" & i) = "=" & "Average(E" & i & ":" & "E" & (numRows1 + 1) & ")"
        Else
          DataSheet.Range("f" & i) = DataSheet.Range("f25")
        End If
    Next

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:01:10"), "GetData"

End Sub
```

Comment: hello experts, I've a file which runs the abv code and keeps on running every minute to get me updated data on a stock (GOOGLE).. abv codes includes with two worksheet.. I want to add same two more worksheet to run to other stock say (YAHOO) in the same xls.. will it be possible using the same VBA or will need to add similiar vba code if so, what are the changes i need to make with abv codes .. please help.. I tried using opening two files separately after renaming but it was not updating.. together only updates last accessed or active excel sheet

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You really ought to move the comment above into the text of your question (probably before your code sample). I didn't realize it was there when I looked at your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can condense your code by using an outer loop that changes from one sheet to the next and populates each with a different dataset based on your lookup value.

One way is to pass the ticker as an argument

```
Call LoadFromYahoo("MSFT")
Call LoadFromYahoo("BOA")
...
```

Or you could put a list of tickers on one sheet and read the list, adding new worksheets for each ticker, then loading the data and renaming the tab to the ticker.

```
public sub    LoadFromYahoo()

  Dim tWS as worksheet
  dim aCell as range
  dim sWS as worksheet

  set sws = thisworkbook.sheets("Sheet1")    'List of tickers in column A
  for each acell in intersect(sws.range("A1").entirecolumn, sws.usedrange)
    set tws = worksheets.add
    with tws
       call GetFromYahoo(acell.value)  'function to make your yahoo call
    end with
  next acell

exit sub
```